# memory issue in jni

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

i am calling java code in c++ application using JNI

for exucuting java code it's taking 10GB ,after executing function(in side am calling java  code) in c++  ,its not releasing memory ,but if i close the application then its releasing  memory ,can you please help me out of this

Comment: The JVM allocate virtual memory on startup, which is used for the heap etc. and generally doesn't release it until it stops. If you run the JVM as a separate process it would behave as you expect.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - that should be an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

The JVM allocates virtual memory on startup, which is used for the heap etc. and generally doesn't release it until it stops. It does this because the heap is managed memory, which the JVM expects to manage it's way.  This works best for long running processes but doesn't play so nicely for point solutions as you have.

If you run the JVM as a separate process it would behave as you expect.